# #include<boost> no such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, boost, g++

when trying to compile a gnu plot example, g++ compiler complains that it cannot find the boost library which is located in /usr/include/boost.

to be exact:

> fatal error: boost: No such file or directory #include

i've used the command

`g++ -l /usr/include/boost  -Wall -std=c++11 -lboost_iostreams exampleplot.cpp  -o exampleplot.out`

have also tried `g++ -I /usr/include/boost/*  -Wall -std=c++11 -lboost_iostreams exampleplot.cpp  -o exampleplot.out`

here are my includes:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
#include <boost>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and advise how to fix?

Comment: There's no `boost` file.

Comment: `<boost>` is not a standard library. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) for how to include the headers you want to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no header file accessible using

```
#include <boost>
```

You'll need to specify a concrete boost header, you want to use in your code, e.g.

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
```

Comment: Is this new in c++ because the example i used referred to just boost as i did

Comment: @bbpy-newb That's probably a bug in the example. Is it available online?

Comment: @bbpy-newb Not that I know about. I never used it differently.

Comment: Should be. I'll let them know there's a problem. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Briefly leaving this here due to question deletion: [re your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828492/copying-a-value-passed-as-reference#comment42224473_26828492) _obviously_ not! I've noticed a trend that you often jump to incorrect conclusions on a post, often suggesting them as duplicates based on an incorrect premise. Just a heads up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was thinking about that not shown _'by reference return value'_ could cause some strange and unexpected behavior. I should have chosen a different wording of course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You'd really struggle to have a dangling reference to a `char` that's promptly copied to cause a local `vector` to report double frees. In fact, I can't think of any implementation on which that'd happen.